# Deleting A File Within An APK Without Making The APK/App Unusable

Tags: android, apk

Is it possible to include a raw resource in an APK (ex: strings.txt) and permanently delete it during runtime on the device the APK has been installed to? My understanding is that the original packaged APK must remain on the Android device untouched in order for the app to run properly. If the APK was unpacked and the strings.txt file deleted - could the APK be packaged again on the device and saved as the only APK file?

Comment: Why are you trying to delete a file after the build process? Like what benefit do you see in doing so? `strings.txt` is already part of the APK, so it will be loaded onto the Android device as part of the APK. It sounds like you may be trying to prevent the user from seeing some (required) aspect of your application, in which case deleting the file is definitely not the way to go about it.

Comment: You are correct on both aspects - I am trying hide sensitive information (strings) from a user/hacker and this is not the correct way to go about it. A better solution would be to access a restricted API that provides these sensitive strings. I am still curious though if this is even possible.

Comment: That's definitely the way to go, and very possible :) All you need to do is make a request to a server-side page that gives you the details (or handles authentication outright if you're working with logins), and then simply not display them to the end user. The file will never be in the APK; the file will be stored on the (protected) server.

Comment: I'm glad we're on the same page on what the best implementation would be for this is :). I just want to keep this question open to see if there might be some way possible to still delete a file within the apk and have it still be usable. Simply out of curiosity is why I want to know this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not, though I believe there is reason to do this -- prevent reverse engineering of our asset data.

APK integrity is guaranteed by the signing process which uses the private key (jks). If you want to do Repackage, you will need the jks file at the user's device, this is absolutely not wanted.

Google play store is trying to replace apk with app bundles which claims to reduce the download size of the application. In that case Play store will do the re-package for you but you have to rely on Play store to manage your private key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That makes sense that you would need the private key in order to repackage and that would definitely not work from a security standpoint having that on a user's device. That factor alone would rule out the possibility of using this implementation.